# Can't find Pi Point after create

Tags: osisoft

I have C# application that creates a new Pi Point using the code based on 
PI-AF-SDK-Basic-Samples/CreatePIPointsExample.cs at master · osisoft/PI-AF-SDK-Basic-Samples · GitHub

The point seems to be created ok - here's a screen grab following a tag search in SMT:

[image]

My problem is, when my same C# application searches for the newly created Pi Point is doesn't find it.
The code for the search is as follows:

```
private static List<PIPoint> GetPiPoints(PIServer piServer)
        {
            var criteria = GetCriteria("61");
            var foundPoints = PIPoint.FindPIPoints(piServer, criteria).ToList();

            criteria = GetCriteria("63");
            foundPoints.AddRange(PIPoint.FindPIPoints(piServer, criteria).ToList());


            criteria = GetCriteria("64");
            foundPoints.AddRange(PIPoint.FindPIPoints(piServer, criteria).ToList());


            return foundPoints;
        }

private static List<PIPointQuery> GetCriteria(string location)
        {
            List<PIPointQuery> criteria = new List<PIPointQuery>();

            PIPointQuery whereClause1 = new PIPointQuery(PICommonPointAttributes.Location1, OSIsoft.AF.Search.AFSearchOperator.Equal, location);
            PIPointQuery whereClause2 = new PIPointQuery(PICommonPointAttributes.PointSource, OSIsoft.AF.Search.AFSearchOperator.Equal, "o");

            criteria.Add(whereClause1);
            criteria.Add(whereClause2);

            return criteria;
        }
```

So, my understanding is that this should find all points that have a "location1" attribute value of 61, 63 or 61 AND a "pointSource" of "o" - I have tried uppercase and lower case "o"

From the screenshot, you can see that this is the case for the newly created "Kuba_99x" tag yet it is not found in the search, although thousands of other existing tags are.

Any ideas where I went wrong please?

Comment: How many tags are found in the 1st search?  Is it over 100K?

Comment: Your code looks fine.  There may be problems with your PI Server.  You may need to call OSIsoft TechSupport, but let them know I said it's not a code problem.

Comment: Number of tags found 2457.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pi code was actually fine. Problem was, my code was filtering the newly created record after the selection.

Answer (score 1):

**Location1** is stored as an Int32 on the PI Data Archive.  The `location` parameter needs to be an `int` instead of `string`.

Further questions will be addressed at OSIsoft PI Square since you also have a post there.

Comment: Thanks Rick I will try that but how come existing Pi Points are found by the search? The only ones that don't get found are those created by the C# application

Comment: @RobBowman What happens if you omit comment out 63 and 64 and only search on 61?  Is the point still not found?

Comment: Yes, still not found. In fact that's how I had it written yesterday

Comment: @RobBowman When I see something so squirrely for something so simple, it's usually time for a server reboot.

Comment: Haha, I know what you mean. Unfortunately this server has been rebooted several times. It's an Azure VM which I stop each night because I'm a Yorkshireman 